# Parse JSON multilevel array and find key values on multiple levels

Tags: php, json, parsing

I need help to find/print all the values in a given array.

I can get all values on 'level 1' of array but no deeper. What is the generic code for parsing multilevel arrays. I figure if I can parse the api json then I can do anything else required with the data.

I also get Array to string conversion warnings yet I'm explicitly naming the element - I must be missing something.

```
<?php
$drugs = fopen("http://dgidb.org/api/v2/interactions.json?drugs=FICLATUZUMAB", "r");
$json_drugs = stream_get_contents($drugs);
fclose($drugs);
$data_drugs = json_decode($json_drugs,true);

print_r($data_drugs);        // Dump all data of the Array

foreach ($data_drugs as $key => $value)
    {
    if (empty($value[0]["searchTerm"])) {echo "-<br>";} else {echo "searchTerm  : " . $value[0]["searchTerm"] . "<br>";};
    if (empty($value[0]["searchTerm"])) {echo "-<br>";} else {echo "searchTerm  : " . $value[0]["searchTerm"] . "<br>";};
    if (empty($value[0]["drugName"])) {echo "-<br>";} else {echo "drugName  : " . $value[0]["drugName"] . "<br>";};
    if (empty($value[0]["chemblId"])) {echo "-<br>";} else {echo "chemblId  : " . $value[0]["chemblId"] . "<br>";};
    if (empty($value[0]["interactions"])) {echo "INTERACTIONS : NONE" . "<br>";} else {echo "INTERACTIONS : " . $value[0]["interactions"] . "<br>";};
    if (empty($value[0]["interactions"][0]["interactionId"])) {echo "-<br>";} else {echo ">InteractionId  : " . $value[0]["interactions"][0]["interactionId"] . "<br>";};
    if (empty($value[0]["interactions"][0]["interactionTypes"])) {echo "INTERACTION TYPES : NONE" . "<br>";} else {echo ">Interaction Types : " . $value[0]["interactions"][0]["interactionTypes"] . "<br>";};
    foreach ($data_drugs as $key => $value)
          {
          if (empty($value[0]["interactions"][0]["interactionTypes"][0])) {echo "-";} else {echo ">>interactionTypes : " . $value[0]["interactions"][0]["interactionTypes"][0] . "<br>";};
          }
    if (empty($value[0]["interactions"][0]["geneName"])) {echo "-<br>";} else {echo ">GeneName  : " . $value[0]["interactions"][0]["geneName"] . "<br>";};
    if (empty($value[0]["interactions"][0]["geneLongName"])) {echo "-<br>";} else {echo ">GeneLongName  : " . $value[0]["interactions"][0]["geneLongName"] . "<br>";};
    if (empty($value[0]["interactions"][0]["geneEntrezId"])) {echo "-<br>";} else {echo ">GeneEntrezId  : " . $value[0]["interactions"][0]["geneEntrezId"] . "<br>";};
    if (empty($value[0]["interactions"][0]["sources"])) {echo "SOURCES : NONE" . "<br>";} else {echo ">Sources : " . $value[0]["interactions"][0]["sources"] . "<br>";};
    if (empty($value[0]["interactions"][0]["sources"][0])) {echo "-<br>";} else {echo ">>sources : " . $value[0]["interactions"][0]["sources"][0] . "<br>";};
    if (empty($value[0]["interactions"][0]["pmids"])) {echo ">PMIDs  : NONE" . "<br>";} else {echo ">PMIDs  : " . $value[0]["interactions"][0]["pmids"] . "<br>";};
    if (empty($value[0]["interactions"][0]["pmids"][0])) {echo "-<br>";} else {echo ">>PMIDs  : " . $value[0]["interactions"][0]["pmids"][0] . "<br>";};
    if (empty($value[0]["interactions"][0]["score"])) {echo "-<br>";} else {echo ">Score  : " . $value[0]["interactions"][0]["score"] . "<br>";};
      }
?>
```

I can get all values on 'level 1' of array but no deeper. What is the generic code for parsing multilevel arrays. I figure if I can parse the api json then I can do anything else required with the data.

I also get Array to string conversion warnings yet I'm explicitly naming the element.

Comment: You should consider using a recursive function that traverses the entire array.

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: No, I felt there was not enough information in your answer that I could apply.

Comment: I now have it working with 4 'for' loops cycling through the levels to echo values but it's lengthy and requires a complete rewrite for each new api call type. Ideally, I'd like to echo the keys instead of hard coding key values and have a simple algorithm that works on any array structure.

Comment: I don't recall giving you an answer... and again, you're probably looking for a recursive function(_simple algorithm_) to traverse your array. That way you have complete flexibility (i.e. no hard coding required) to elegantly handle arrays of different size and depth.

Comment: Yes, you were on the right track - I got a simple recursive function here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63637498/how-do-i-loop-through-multidimensional-json-array/63641051?noredirect=1#comment112570309_63641051

Comment: Glad it worked out for you!