# How do I loop through multidimensional JSON array in PHP?

Tags: php, json, parsing

I want to write code to loop through a multidimensional array (4 or 5 deep) and echo all keys and values found and skip empty arrays.

```
$drugs = fopen("http://dgidb.org/api/v2/interactions.json?drugs=FICLATUZUMAB", "r");
$json_drugs = stream_get_contents($drugs);
fclose($drugs);
$data_drugs = json_decode($json_drugs,true);

foreach ($data_drugs as $key => $value) 
...
```

Anyone, anyone, Ferris?

Comment: Use a recursive function.

Comment: Echo everything inside the array? Well... `print_r($data_drugs);` try this. You do not need `foreach`, put print_r right after json_decode

Comment: print_r($data_drugs); no I want to touch each array element - if I can do that then I can do anything with the array content eg add formatting, logic, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $data_drugs is no longer a json, after json_decode is an associative array.
You don't need any loop to see keys and values

```
$data_drugs = json_decode($json_drugs,true);
print_r($data_drugs);

/* or if you don't like inline */

echo'<pre>';
print_r($data_drugs);
echo'</pre>';
```

You can use `var_dump($data_drugs)` - keys and values with types, probably you don't need this
But if you want to display keys and values more ...fancy use a recursive function

```
function show($x){
    foreach($x as $key=>$val){
        echo"<p>$key : ";
        if(is_array($val)){ echo". . ."; show($val);}
        else{ echo"$val</p>";}}}

show($data_drugs);
```

Comment: I like it, very elegant. Is this what is called a recursive function (as suggested by @Barmar above ), ie it calls itself?

Comment: @barnyard my function show() is not ... well, it's a lazy version, it takes a bit more to get a really elegant display :)  And yes, it is recursive - self calling. In php to call a function you have to enter its name (with necessary parameters) - like last line. show() in 4th line has a condition - if the processed value is an array - then - self-calling: "do me for this particular value", it is nothing special, one of the methods. And yes, proper use is elegant

Comment: Well it touches each element (key and value) without hardcoding index names (like my own attempt) in a short reusable function - I think its elegant because it's so simple, the output formatting is decoration. Thanks @black blue